# How to bind array of string to List of Enum in DTO class - C# WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums, binding

I have a DTO record like so:

```cs
public record MessageDto {
    [Required] 
    public string Content { get; init; }

    public List<MessageType> Types { get; init;}
}
```

where `MessageType` looks like this:

```cs
public enum MessageType {
    Sms,
    Email
}
```

Now, when I'm sending this json message via API it all works (in this case, sms shows as binded element in `Types`:

```json
{
  "content": "test",
  "types": [
    0
  ]
}
```

but when I'm sending json like this:

```json
{
  "content": "test",
  "types": [
    "Sms"
  ]
}
```

I'm getting `400 Error: Bad Request`.

Controller is very basic:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] MessageDto messageDto) {
    // Body...
}
```

This string "Sms" doesn't bind to `Types` list.
How can I force this kind of binding from array of string to list of enums?

Comment: var enumStrings = new[] {"Sms", "Email"};
var enumValues = enumStrings.Select(fs => (MessageType)Enum.Parse(typeof (MessageType), fs));